# Copy a dynamic page in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic

My knowledge of Rails is pretty basic, but I have to fix a problem in a Rails project and the programmer can not be reached. So I'm trying to fix it myself, but I'm stuck.

The project revolves around user being able to add pictures to competitions, and to be able to vote on those pictures. The plan was to have to voting on the same page as the images, but this gives a few bugs in the JS and slow performance. So I want to have the voting and the overview on two different pages.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to create another page inside the views > competitions folder and link it up with the rest of the project. The easiest solution for me would be to copy the show.html.haml and paste it like votepage.html.haml but obviously that isn't so easy.

in the view > competitions folder there's an index.html.haml file, this displays a list of current competitions and gives a admin the ability to remove, add or edit certain competitions.  When a user clicks on a link to a competition this gets rendered in the show.html.haml. On this page all the images that have been uploaded in that competition are shown. On that page I want a link that refers to the voting section. When a user clicks that link it should go to the votepage.html.haml (which is 100% the same as the show.html.haml but with different styling and added javascript). For now there's no need to actually make the voting work, "faking" it through front-end is good enough.

TLDR: I want to copy/paste a page in a view, but I don't know how to hook it up to the project.

Update1. I've used the console command `rails generate controller competitions votepage` which created a votepage for me. I could visit this one as well on `http://localhost:3000/competitions/votepage`

With the following code

```
- @competitions.each do |competition|
  #container.js-masonry
    .painting.item
      = link_to competition do
        - competition.pictures.shuffle.each do |picture|
          = image_tag(picture.image_url)
```

I can insert images from the competitions in the page. But the problem is that I gets images from all competitions. And not so much competitions/1 , competitions/2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is updating the routes file so that Rails knows what you want

Views:

```
competitions/
  show.html.haml
  vote.html.haml
  ...
```

Routes:

```
resources :competitions do
  get :vote, on: :member
end
```

Member makes it behave like the show action, requiring a format like competitions/:id/vote

Edit:

```
You want to do the routes like above, but in the controller, make sure you get the competition from the id that will get passed
```

Controller:

```
def vote
  @competition = Competition.find(params[:id])
end
```

And then instead of looping through all the competitions, you can just take the loop out and reference `@competition`

Comment: Can you post the code in the question so it formats better?

Comment: This is looking very good! How do I go about getting a `= link_to` the specific votepage? If I use this `= link_to 'Vote!', votepage, :class => "buttons"` I get a `undefined local variable or method `votepage'` allthough this link works http://localhost:3000/competitions/3/votepage

Comment: You're almost there, you can do `link_to "Vote!", vote_competition_path(competition.id), class: "buttons"`

Comment: With `= link_to 'Vote!', votepage_competition_path(competition.id), class: "buttons"` I get a `undefined local variable or method `competition'` but when I remove the `(competition.id)` it seems to work fine.

Comment: Are you linking from the index page or the show page? If on the index page, then you competition is defined in the scope of a loop (`@competitions.each do |competition|`). But if on the show page, then you show have a variable `@competition`, if not, then you can define it in your controller with `@competition = Competition.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is that you also need to copy the show method from app/controllers/competitions and make a votepage method with the contents in the same file.

This guide will help explain how views get wired (by the controller) to models: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: If I look up the `competitions_controller.rb` the `show` method is empty though.